# Is the Tr $({\bf A}) < 0$ for ${\bf A}$ a negative definite matrix.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

Where Tr$({\bf A})$ denotes the sum of the diagonal of the square matrix ${\bf A}$ of size n. ${\bf A}$ comprised of all real elements, with real eigenvalues $\lambda_n<0$.

Comment: According to you definition: is a negaitve definite matrix necessarily symmetric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look back in your textbook for the *definition* of a negative definite matrix.  Using that, we can say that if $e_1,\dots,e_n$ is the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$, we have $e_k^TAe_k < 0$ for all $k$, which means that
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A) = \sum_{k=1}^n e_k^TAe_k < 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the trace of a matrix $A$ is also equal to the sum of the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: It's always the simple facts you forget, thank you.